# Is it possible to measure energy consumption from power socket?

Tags: energy, power-consumption

I wanted to know if it is possible to measure how much energy is being consumed in the entire house by plugging in a power meter in any power outlet in the house?

I am aware of some portable meters but they can only measure energy consumed that specific appliances but not of entire house.

Sorry if the question sounds stupid, i am new here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once heard someone describing such a device and was very confused.
The usual method is something like the Kill-A-Watt, which goes between the appliance you're measuring, and the wall. But this can only measure the consumption of something plugged into it!
[image: kill-a-watt]

It turned out to be possible. A smart meter (mounted at the main board) communicates over the power lines with an indoor terminal, plugged into any outlet in the house.
Here is a picture of one:
[image: split prepaid meter]

They are most commonly used for prepaid meters, where the metering and control is done outside on the pole, and the user just plugs the indoor terminal into any wall outlet. It then displays the power consumption of the whole house, and allows credit to be added to the meter.

In some cases it might be possible that even though you have a regular billing electricity meter, you have the option of buying a plug-in unit which reads the consumption from the meter.

Comment: This doesn't even require a smart meter. There's a version with a simple wireless current clamp fitting over the incoming "Live" (after the isolator!) and a voltage monitor/logger/display that plugs into the wall socket. http://www.southern-electric.co.uk/HelpAndAdvice/iplan/iplansetup/ ... NB "not currently available" according to the website.

Comment: @briandrummond true, that looks quite neat. But if you install it yourself then you're not really just *"plugging in a power meter in any power outlet in the house"*. What got me was the surprise factor that some houses are already fitted for this, and it may be possible to simply plug in the display.

Answer (score 3):

Energy is the accumulation (or integration) of power over time.

Power is voltage x current.

To measure current you need to have something that is "in-line" with the current flow.

You can't do that from any particular outlet.

If you can't determine what the current taken is you can't calculate power.

If you can't calculate power you can't determine energy consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. It's just like the plumbing in your house - you can't tell how much water is flowing out of the shower by looking at the tap in the kitchen. You have to either put a meter on the outlet you want to measure or install one on the main pipe into the house. It is exactly the same with electricity.

Comment: Thanks.. I was thinking the same but thought to post it to get it outta my head 

Answer (score 0):

the better and safety way to measure current is to use a coil surrounding the wires comming from outside. You can found split transformers (i have forgotten the right name) on ebay for less than 10$

Comment: Hhhmmmm wouldn't you have to place it by the main meter?

Comment: I don't understand your question...

Comment: Google for "split-core current transformer".  @Lokapedia, I don't know if it would be a code violation, but you could put one or two (depending on what country you live in) on the wire(s) feeding the main breaker inside your distribution panel.